# The background-color property with rgba() is making text blur and harder to read - CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am using background-color property to my webpage wrapper like this -

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
```

But it is creating problem for me. It is making top navigation menu link text blur and harder to read.

[image]

When I remove transparency from wrapper's background-color, then all is fine. Interestingly when I scroll my webpage then all becomes also fine.

[image]

Here is my HTML -

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper starts here -->
    <div id="top_nav"> <!-- nav starts here -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="search_form">
            <form method="get" action="">
                <input type="text" name="txtsearch" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    </div> <!-- nav ends here -->
</div>
```

Here is my CSS -

```
#wrapper
{
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

#top_nav
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3079ED;
    position:relative;
}

#top_nav ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#top_nav ul li
{
    float:left;
}

#top_nav ul li a
{
    background-color:#3079ED;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:8px 16px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    border-right:1px solid #6199DF;
}

#top_nav ul li:last-child a
{
    border-right:none;
}

#top_nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color:#6199DF;
}
```

So please tell me how can I make my menu link text clean and more readable as regular text while keeping the transparency.

EDIT -

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/php123/06yagehc/8/)

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dnbwuaa/) of the code above. I should note, I don't see a difference in rendering on Chrome 37 on Mac OS X. So, you might post your browser and OS too.

Comment: ok sure i will put my code to jsfiddle. i think there will be something more that is affecting the look. i am also using body background image as fixed cover.

Comment: In #wrapper you are using background-color twice, please delete on of them.

Comment: no, that is not an issue. it is for the browsers who don't support rgba().